# Java Procedure Call failing with InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I have a java code, that need to execute the procedure and procedure takes two inputs and one out parm. I have my code as shown below, but the code is failing with this error

org.springframework.dao.**InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException**: Unable to determine the correct call signature - no procedure/function/signature for PROC

```
final SimpleJdbcCall sourceStatusProc = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("PROC");

    final SqlParameterSource sourceParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("parm1", parm1)
            .addValue("param2", param2);

    // Executing stored procedure
    Map<String, Object> StatusIdObject = sourceStatusProc.execute(sourceParameters);
```

Comment: Post full stack trace. That will help others to help you.

Comment: InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException => Exception thrown on incorrect usage of the API, such as failing to "compile" a query object that needed compilation before execution.

Comment: I think found the issue, the user privileges  were not properly set, and its fixed now. Thank you for your comments.